# Отображение на главной странице

Tags: php

Как составить PHP скрипт, что бы элемент не отображался **только** на главной странице. Можете объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if($page['path']=="/index.php" or $page['path']=="/")
echo "Это главная страничка";
else
echo "Это не главная страничка";
```

Что-то такое, будут вопросы, пиши ссылку на главную страничку сюда

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, если  Вы используете переменну к примеру `$page`, которая символизирует назвнаие странички, тогда просто делаем так:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 'index' or $_GET['page'] == ''){
//...
}
```

Comment: or $_GET['page'] == '' - зачем нужно это?

Comment: К примеру часто делаю сайты с такой структурой
К примеру: